# Calling and coloring the variables inside HTML message

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm asking for your help :)
How could I call and color all variables inside the "var message"?
I'm using regular string type for message for now but I would like to use HTML text with ability to change font size and color. I'm the end of the code you have my bad version of that text :)

Thanks in advance

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = rows.getValues();
for (i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var currentShop = row[7] - 200000;
  var expectedShop = row[1] - 200000;

if(row[12] == "PL") {
  var Package = "Pilnie C&C-" + row[0];
} else {
    var Package = "Urgent C&C-" + row[0];
       }

var emailAddress = currentShop + "@gmail.com, " + expectedShop + "@gmail.com" ;

if(row[12] == "PL") {

  var message = "Drogi sklepie..... "

    } else {

      var message = "Hello shop " + currentShop + " (" + row[12] + ")," + '\n\n' + "according to the information in the system," + '\n' + "the parcel num. " + row[0] + '\n' + "was delivered to YOUR shop instead of to the correct one " + expectedShop + "(" + row[6] + ")." + '\n' + "Please check it and answer this e-mail. The parcel should be sent to the correct shop." + '\n' + "In case of any questions, please, contact me;

           }

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, Package, message);
   }
};
```

```
<html>
<body>

Drogi sklepie <span style='color:red; '><strong><?= currentShop;?> ( <?=row[12];?> )</strong>,</span> <br><br>
wedle informacji z systemu, <br>
zamówienie <span style='color:orange; '><strong>nr <?=row[0];?></strong></span> <br> 
zamiast Waszego sklepu, powinno byæ przes³ane kurierem do sklepu <span style='color:green; '><strong><?=expectedShop;?> (<?=row[6];?>)</strong></span>. <br>
Proszê o sprawdzenie tego i odpowiedzenie na ten e-mail. <br>
W przypadku pytañ, proszê o kontakt ze mną

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want HTML-formatted body for the message, right? If so, you should add `options` argument to `MailApp.sendEmail()` call (see the `MailApp` [reference for details](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))), set its `htmlBody` property and write your `HtmlString` to it (alternatively, you can write it in via `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(yourFileName).evaluate()`, since you are using template variables)